# Typeorm Migrations generates default value repeatedly

Tags: postgresql, migration, nestjs, typeorm

When I use the default value in an entity column it appears repeatedly in the migration-generated file.

for example following line is exist in all newly generated migrations even though the last run migration included them

```
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "forget_passwords" ALTER COLUMN "expired_at" SET 
    DEFAULT (now() + '00:03:00'::interval)`);
```

How can I fix them once and for all time?